# customize sorting of a column in vba to show an item first

Tags: excel, vba, tablesorter

I have a big table in excel, which contains about 8000 rows of data. I am working on a procedure to enable the users to receive a pdf copy of what they are looking for. (A detail list related to a work order). 
I tried two different approaches, first copying the work order items after filtering it to a third sheet and then copying selected fields of data to the final form. It was good and fast.
second, after filter directly copying data of unhidden rows to the final form. (also more sort and remove duplicated items happen too)
The second one is very time killing (3 to 5 minutes) and very heavy. 
Now, I am thinking of first sorting the data in a way that my desired item (what the user is looking for) comes to the first of table so after the filter, I just ask the loop to go until a visible number of rows, not until the end of rows. 
Has anyone any idea, or better solution? 
Cheers and merry Christmas!

```
Sub kit_Click()
' On Error GoTo Errorhandler
Dim wc As String
Dim c As Integer
Dim tbl As Range
Dim sel As Range
Dim des As Range
Dim m As Integer
Dim j As Integer
Dim aggrow As Integer
Dim varResult As Variant
Dim kf As Worksheet
Set kf = Worksheets("Kit Form")
a = ""

'    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
' finding W/B code to prepare
If Not Intersect(ActiveCell, Range("d2:d3")) Is Nothing Then
    a = Cells(2, 7).Value
    GoTo body
ElseIf ActiveCell.Row < 6 Then a = InputBox("please specify the W/B you want to prepare KIT form for that", "W/B Number")
ElseIf ActiveCell.Row > ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count Then a = InputBox("please specify the W/B you want to prepare KIT form for that", "W/B Number")
Else: a = Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value
End If
body:
On Error GoTo skip
 wc = WorksheetFunction.VLookup(a, Range("b5:c1000"), 2, 0)
skip:
If a = "" Or a = "0" Then
     a = InputBox("please specify the W/B you want to prepare KIT form for that", "W/B Number")
Else
    ' Cleaning KIT FORM
        If Not kf.ListObjects("KitForm").DataBodyRange Is Nothing Then kf.ListObjects("KitForm").DataBodyRange.EntireRow.Delete
    ' Filtering the W/B Kittable items
    With Sheets("FTV3")
        .Range("tbl").AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:="*" & a & "*", Operator:=xlFilterValues
        .Range("tbl").AutoFilter Field:=25, Criteria1:="OK", Operator:=xlFilterValues
    ' Unhidding the Columns and copying the header row
        .Cells.EntireColumn.Hidden = False
    ' Copying the data to Form
    lstrw = .Cells(Rows.Count, 8).End(xlUp).Row
        kf.Cells(2, 2) = a
        kf.Cells(1, 4) = wc
        m = 1
    For i = 2 To lstrw
    If .Rows(i).EntireRow.Hidden Then
        m = m + 1
    Else
        kf.Rows(i - m + 4).RowHeight = 25
        kf.Cells(i - m + 4, 1).Value = i - m
        If .Cells(i, 21).Value = "_N/A" Then
            kf.Cells(i - m + 4, 2) = "'"
        Else
            kf.Cells(i - m + 4, 2) = .Cells(i, 21)
        End If
        kf.Cells(i - m + 4, 3).Value = .Cells(i, 4).Value
        If .Cells(i, 4).Value <> "_Book" Then kf.Cells(i - m + 4, 4).Value = .Cells(i, 26).Value
        Worksheets("Kit Form").Cells(i - m + 4, 5).Value = .Cells(i, 7).Value
        If .Cells(i, 8).Value <> "N/T" Then kf.Cells(i - m + 4, 6).Value = .Cells(i, 8).Value
        If .Cells(i, 12).Value <> "_N/A" Then ttt = .Cells(i, 12) 'Or .Cells(i, 22).Value <> ""
        kf.Cells(i - m + 4, 7).Value = "(( " & .Cells(i, 27).Value & " ))" & Chr(10) & ttt
        kf.Rows(i - m + 4).AutoFit
        If kf.Rows(i - m + 4).RowHeight < 25 Then kf.Rows(i - m + 4).RowHeight = 25
    End If
    Next
    .Range("A:B,S:ac").EntireColumn.Hidden = True
    aggrow = kf.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 4
    .Range("tbl").AutoFilter
    End With
    Call remove_duplicate
    R = MsgBox("Successfuly Total of " & lstrw - m - 1 & " Items, aggregated in " & aggrow & " Rows of material Copied to the Kit Form " & Chr(10) & Chr(10) & "Do you want an PDF version of The form being prepared for you?", vbYesNo, "Result")
        If R = 6 Then Call export_pdf
End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I would suggest you time each section of your script to know what is the most time-consuming - generally a good idea before you start dramatically changing your script. One way:. 'Dim tStart As Single
'tStart = Timer . Then you can just do print Timer - tStart at various points. Not the best timer option but good enough for start. Do a couple runs (not stable - if you computer hangs it will false the results).

Comment: It is always recommended to disable event handling and screen updating in macros. This is especially for heavy macros and when you are concerned with timing. You should do that *BEFORE thinking of anything else* to optimize the macro.